# How to enable editing mode for all cells, not just visible ones

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, setediting

In my app I want to allow the user to press a button that enables them to change the order of the tableview cells.

I am using  `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

However, when the user presses the button and then scrolls, the cells that were not visible when the button was pressed do not have editing mode enabled.

I read this in Apple's documentation: "When you call this method with the value of editing set to true, the table view goes into editing mode by calling setEditing(_:animated:) on each *visible* UITableViewCell object."

Is there a way to enable **all** cells to be in editing mode despite not being visible when editing mode is enabled?

Here are some snapshots:

[After enabling editing mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOI5w.png)

[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQXfP.png)

Comment: Can you please add some code on the tableview that you were using?

Comment: what kind of code?

Answer (score 1):

When you call`[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` you can also do something like set a custom `BOOL` property to `YES` to indicate that other cells should be in editing mode when they are displayed.

Then, in your `UITableViewDelegate`, you can implement the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and call `setEditing(_:animated:)` on the cell if your editing flag is `YES`. Just make sure to also set the flag to `NO` when you don't want this to happen anymore.